# How many gold coins would you have to smelt to make a bottle out of them?

Tags: dnd-5e, crafting

I've been tasked by a party member to make a bottle out of gold. I have no ingots, but I have a mold, and gold currency. If I wanted to make a standard canteen sized bottle how many gold coins would it take to make it?

I do not want to heat the gold multiple times, and I do not want to have extra molten gold. At least not more than I need. I do understand there will almost always be a little extra, or a little less. I could potentially weigh them, but with a canteen bottle being made out of plastic, it's hard to find a good weight ratio.

Comment: Which game are you playing? I assume that different systems may design their currencies with different characteristics, such as size.

Comment: We're playing 5e

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a real-world research question (on gold bottle-making) with no apparent bearing on RPG rules or expertise beyond the in-game properties of a gold coin. This may have more bearing on actual RPG expertise if you ask how you can go about crafting a gold bottle (without necessarily assuming it needs to be done via melting down gold coins, but mentioning you're willing to do that is fair), which is probably [better being asked separately](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4813/1204) since it's a fundamentally different question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## 375 Gold Coins

Weight of an empty bottle of wine (75cl): **0.39 kg** [(source)](http://www.novinpak.org/eco-calculateur)

Density of glass: **2.21** [(source)](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/density-solids-d_1265.html)

Density of gold: **19.29**

Weight of a gold bottle the exact same shape than a glass wine bottle: 
    (0.39 × 19.29) / 2.21 ≈ **3.404kg**

The weight of a gold coin in D&D 5e is “about a third of an ounce, so fifty coins weigh a pound” (PHB, p. 143), which is: **9.07g**

The minimal number of coin needed for such a bottle (no tinkering errors, spillage...): 3404 / 9.07 ≈ **375**

So you would need **375 coins**.

Comment: Is it worth mentioning that in 5e, 50 coins are estimated to weigh about 1lb, so one coin is around 1/50th lb, or 9 grams? Meaning you'd need around 3.5 times more. So ~350 coins? (Source: 5e SRD. "A standard coin weighs about a third of an ounce, so fifty coins weigh a pound.")

Comment: Good clarification !

Comment: @CyriusN. If you like the info from the comment, please fold it into your answer with an edit since comments eventually go away.